# Filter by specific amenity in OSM

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I'm new to maps, and have been searching for the past couple of hours how to get started with OpenStreetMaps without much success.

What I would like is a spreadsheet with the coordinates, names and addresses of all the fast food restaurants in Dublin, Ireland which I could then paste into something like batchgeo and explore.

I initially tried to go to openstreetmaps and restrict what it showed to just the Tag:amenity=fast_food but I couldn't see a way to do that.

So I've now downloaded the osm file from cloudmade and opened it in JOSM, but I'm not seeing how to remove the layers.

Could one of you guys tell me the simplest way to achieve what I'd like? Thanks.

An update for those keeping score, I've now got the file into osmosis and am trying to filter it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the OSM base using

`http://jxapi.openstreetmap.org/xapi/api/0.6/node[amenity=fast_food][bbox=16.26,48.18,16.31,48.20]`

just adjust the bounding box

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I'll go find the box coordinates for Dublin!

Comment: This link appears to do the job for ya: http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/